# data-toggle="tab" not keeping same sizes for tabs

Tags: html, css, class, dotnetnuke, tabpanel

My tabs are changing every time that a switch tabs, for example, some are wider examples:
[image]

When I click Policies
[image]

Code is the same so why does this happen?

```
<div class="tabs tabs-vertical tabs-left">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabsNavigationSimplebg5"><span>Videos 
&amp;&nbsp;Docs</span></a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabsNavigationSimplebg6">Policies</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabsNavigationSimplebg7">District Shared Resources</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabsNavigationSimplebg8">Left Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Nonworking Tab

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tabsNavigationSimplebg5">
<div class="left">
<h4>Videos &amp; Documentation</h4>
```

Working tab

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tabsNavigationSimplebg6">
<div class="left">
<h4>Policies</h4>
```

Comment: Seems like it's based on content of the tab. Without seeing css nobody could possibly answer this...

Comment: This is DotNetNuke that's as much as I can provide